# pivot for comma separated values for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a query as follow which give me result set as shown in image

```
SELECT  E1.Name,E1.AccountType ,
        STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(E2.AccountNumber as nvarchar(50))
                FROM    @temp AS e2 
                WHERE   e1.Name = e2.Name and e1.AccountType = e2.AccountType
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') AS AccountNumber ,
          STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(E2.CustomerNumber as nvarchar(50))
                FROM    @temp AS e2 
                WHERE   e1.Name = e2.Name and e1.AccountType = e2.AccountType
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '')  AS CustomerNumber     

FROM    @temp AS e1 
GROUP BY Name,AccountType
```

[image: comma seperated values result]

Now i want to pivot this result set so instead of three rows my result set contains only one row and for `C,I,T` three column for each `AccountNumber`,`CustomerNumber`.

I have written following query to pivot using a single `AccountNumber` column and its working for me but i am not able to get how should i include another column `CustomerNUmber` in this pivot ?

here is query which i written for single column pivot with result set image

```
SELECT  * from 
(
SELECT  E1.Name,E1.AccountType ,
        STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(E2.AccountNumber as nvarchar(50))
                FROM    @temp AS e2 
                WHERE   e1.Name = e2.Name and e1.AccountType = e2.AccountType
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') AS AccountNumber   

FROM    @temp AS e1 
GROUP BY Name,AccountType
) as src 
PIVOT  (MAX(AccountNumber) FOR AccountType IN (C,I,T) )AS pvt
```

[image]

**EDITED :**

[sqlfiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/980d0/3)

Comment: Do you want both account and customer number for C,I,T in the same field or C,I,T for account and a separate C,I,T for customer?

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle with some sample data and your table structure?

Comment: @Tristan yes, you are right . my resulted table should be like this NAME,Account_I,Account_C,Account_T,Customer_I,Customer_C,Customer_T and only one row.

Comment: @bluefeet sql fiddle link included .thanks

Answer (score 0):

--Without Pivot if you just want each group & their corresponding values concatenated

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT E1.[Field_Type]
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN E1.[Field_Type] = b.[Field_Type]
                            THEN ', ' + E2.COLUMN_NAME
                        END
                FROM [DB].[Schema].[Table1] b
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS E2
                    ON E2.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '') AS a
    FROM [DB].[Schema].[Table1] AS e1
    GROUP BY [Field_Type]
    ) AS src
```